# ActionScript Reading A Vector's DataType?

Tags: actionscript-3, vector

is it possible to read the datatype of a vector?

```
var vec:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>;
trace(the datatype of vec);
//ideally this would output 'int'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [describeType](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType()) function who will return you an xml describing the type of your `vec`, and then get the type name that is for a vector enclosed between `<` and `>` or use the function [getQualifiedClassName](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#getQualifiedClassName()) that will return the name of your class.

```
        var name:String = describeType(vec).@name.toString();
        var type:String = name.substring(name.indexOf("<")+1, name.length-1);
        trace(type);


        var name:String = getQualifiedClassName(vec);
        var type:String = name.substring(name.indexOf("<")+1, name.length-1);
        trace(type);
```